# Has RMIRegistry any connection limitation?

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, connection, rmi

I would like to know if Java RMIRegistry has any limitation as to number of concurrent connections.

Comment: Of course - eventually

Answer (score 0):

In practice no. It is only connected to for very brief periods during a bind or lookup operation. Client-side connection pooling will in practice release those connections within a couple of tens of seconds, and server-side read timeouts will take care of any further tidying up required.